# How do I use Python to send emails using my work email address @companyname.com - I am at a small company and they use outlook and MS services

Tags: python, email, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am tring to figure out how I can setup a service to send emails to notify PMs (project managers( at our company once an event happens. We want to use our work email address for this task eg alerts@companyname.com. Our company uses outlook and microsoft services for emails and some other things. I am having trouble using the old way of using SMTP login to connect and send emails. It seems like the new way requires the use of OAuth2 flow. I have followed a couple tutorials online where we create an app on AAD (Azure Active Directory) but I cannot make it work as my Python script is CLI only, there is not GUI and will be running on a server monitoring a DB and just send an email once there is a change.

If you can help me figure out a way to send emails using my work account that would be great. At the moment I am using a google account @gmail account that uses AppPasswords to do this stuff. Thanks!

I have tried some online tutorial but 99% of them are for webapps that redirect you somewhere and then redirect back using redirecturis but I don't need that as my script is running my itself and not involve any user engagement. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Graph API, see [Use the Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api) for more information.